# Statistics Sum involved

Tags: statistics

Q. A soft drinks machine is regulated so that it discharges an average of 7 ounces
per cup. The amount of drink is normally distributed with standard deviation equal to
0.5 ounces.

(a) What is the probability that a cup contains between 6.7 and 7.3 ounces?

(b) How many cups are likely to overflow if 8 ounce cups are used for the next 1000
drinks?

(c) below what value do we get the smallest 25% of the drinks?

Having trouble understanding what I do for part 3. Any help well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By plugging in $.25$ to the inverse normal distribution function, we find that invNorm$(.25)\approx-.67449$

These are the standard deviations below the mean, so $-.67449*0.5$ ounces $=-.33724$ ounces.

Now we subtract this from the mean: $7-.33724$ ounces = $6.66276$ ounces.

We can check this by putting $6.66276$ ounces into the normalCDF:
$$normalCDF(6.66276,7,0.5)\approx.25$$

Comment: Where are you getting -0.67449 from?